# op amp (348) dual supply voltage and feedback capacitor problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

I have to make a transfer function via op amps  G(s)= 100*20*100/((s+10)*(s+20)*(s+100)).I have figured that i need 3 stages of that circuit(obviously the circuit below is only for the first  pole  100/(s+10))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDlCEp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so i used a LM348 and used the 3 741 it contains  .When i omit the capacitor i get correctly for square input of 2 V peak-peak at the output the same square but max value is 10 V because ofcourse my transfer function has 10 V/V voltage gain. However when i connect the capacitors my output is no longer square its sth like sin or triangle and very low voltage , about 300 mV , i believe its something like noise .So the question is this , why capacitor mess up so much my output?

Comment: Why do you believe that you need a capacitor in the feedback loop?

Comment: Sigh... the 384 is from 1978 or 77; why do you still use that? Anyway, you didn't explain why you're even using the capacitors, or why you're even surprised they do what their purpose is.

Comment: i used the capacitors because i need to create those specific poles

Answer (score 1):

> However when i connect the capacitors my output is no longer square its sth like sin or triangle

This is what happens when you low-pass filter a square wave.
Your filter's cut-off frequency is about 1.6 Hz (10 rad/s), so if your square wave is much faster than that, the amplitude will be much reduced.

Comment: u must be correct , i feel so stupid it didnt cross my mind . I remember using high freg.